# how can scripts get the current route location in SPA

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, single-page-application

I am trying to add tracking script in .js file to my angular 12 application.

```
(function() {
    var ds = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    var dm = document.createElement("img");
    dm.width = 1;
    dm.height = 1;
    dm.alt = " ";
    dm.src = "https://example.com/url=" + window.location.href;
    ds.parentNode.insertBefore(dm, ds);
})();
```

Script fires properly on the first page, but doesn't fire on navigating to another page on my website. When i check in elements window.location.href is not changing for the new page. It is because of SPA. How can i get latest location on all pages and script to fire on all pages

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the Angular way, although idk if that will work.

You can go into your root component (should be AppComponent), and simply throw this inside the constructor or `ngOnInit()`

```
@Component({
 ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(router: Router) {
    router.events.pipe(
      filter(route => route instanceof NavigationEnd),
      concatMap((route) => ajax('https://example.com/url=' + route.url)),
    ).subscribe();
  }
}
```

Unless you need your tracker to be an Img for some reason, or you get permission / CORS issues. This should work nicely

Comment: I cant do it in angular. I need to fire it with script in js file

Comment: can't you add the script to a global variable and then fire that on Angular Route?

Comment: i dont know how to do it. Could you please help.

Comment: add another layer of `function` and save it into a variable `window.__myTracker` and then use that from your router interceptor. If that makes sense